# Running php code in html file

Tags: php-5.3

I was processing PHP code in html

```
<h1><?php echo "this is testing" ?></h1>
```

Adding this line in .htaccess

> AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm

It was working in php version 5.2 but while I upgraded my php version to 5.3.6, it stopped working. Any suggestion on how it will support for php 5.3 or above?

Comment: Get rid of the 5. Just use `application/x-httpd-php`.

Comment: not working. I tried with AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .html .htm . Still no luck

Comment: Just to make sure: There actually is a handler attatched to 'application/x-httpd-php'? And you are using mod_php in your apache, not some fastcgi setup?